# Shuffling is not working

Tags: banshee

The shuffling to form the play queuelist is not working. I use Banshee 2.6.1 Apparently the frequency of songs is independent of their rating. The best rated songs should be more frequent. I've tried reinstalling. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When the list is shuffled, all songs are shuffled with an even chance. Think about it like this, when you shuffle a deck of cards, the cards have no way of getting to the top of the deck even if your chances of winning would be increased. Also, with song shuffling, it is performed randomly. How can there be randomness if some of the objects have priority?

Comment: Yes, this is when shuffling by music. I refer to shuffling by rating. In this case, the songs with five stars should be more frequent than those with only one star.

I solved the problem by deleting the file banshee.db. But it took me over three hours to rebuild my library.

Comment: By the way, I once read that in shuffing by ratio, the probability of a five star song be selected is to be equal to the probability of a 4 star song plus to the probability os three stars songs. And so on.